# How to plot data from list?

Tags: list, for-loop, plot

how can I plot data from a list against its indices using a for loop?

(I need do write something because my post is mostly code and I have dot add some more details...)

This is the code sample:

```
import pandas as pd 
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

path = r'D:\Experiments\20210924_SureliteOPO_beampointing\all_log'
filesnames = os.listdir(path)
filesnames = [f for f in filesnames if (f.startswith("2") and f.lower().endswith(".csv"))]

dfs = list() # a list of dataframes
for csvfile in filesnames:
    fpath = path + '/' + csvfile
    df = pd.read_csv(fpath, skiprows=26, skipfooter=5)
    dfs.append(df)
print(dfs)
```

The output looks like this:

```
[    Powermeter1 Start
0            0.001864
1            0.001756
2            0.001818
3            0.001837
4            0.001932
..                ...
95           0.001697
96           0.001950
97           0.001871
98           0.001757
99           0.001849

[100 rows x 1 columns],     Powermeter1 Start
0            0.001771
1            0.001863
2            0.001796
3            0.001885
4            0.001746
..                ...
95           0.001827
96           0.001678
97           0.001813
98           0.001776
99           0.001637

[100 rows x 1 columns]], ...
...
...
```

Regards,

Karl

Answer (score 0):

found it:

```
for i in range(len(dfs)):    
    plt.plot(df.index,dfs[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

`enumerate()` is designed for when you need to loop over an iterable's elements *with* access to their indices:

```
for i, elem in enumerate(dfs):
  ...
```